# Redirecionar usuário sem token

Tags: angular, typescript, token, jwt

Fala galera, bom dia, então estou com um problema e não estou sabendo como resolver, (talvez seja na forma que implementei isso), pois bem:

eu estou salvando um usuario e seu token toda vez que faço login dentro da minha plataforma, caso alguem sem token tente acessar uma rota que necessite de token ele não consegue e é redirecionado para a rota " / ", porém ela aparece sem nada carregado, e não estou sabendo como resolver isso.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-admin',
    templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
    user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    token = this.user.token;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        

    }

    downloadStudents() {
        let url = environment.apiUrl + 'admin/csv';
        this.http.get(url, { responseType: "text" })
            .subscribe(res => {
                let csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + res;
                let data = encodeURI(csv);

                let link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', data);
                link.setAttribute('download', 'alunos.csv');
                link.click();
            })
    }
}
```

esse é meu código.
E como podem ver é assim que eu pego o meu usuário e meu token,

`user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    token = this.user.token;`

será que alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: Depois da uma pesquisada em router guards.

Comment: Valeu Eduardo Vargas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza o método *`navigate`* do *`router`* angular para redirecionar.

```
 constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }
 user; 
 token;
 ngOnInit(){
   this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

   if (!this.user || !this.user.token) 
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
   else
    this.token = this.user.token;
}
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda cara, consegui fazer dessa forma resolveu o problema do redirecionamento, porém percebi que com essa validação no front eu não fico totalmente seguro, estou vendo agora de fazer no back essa validação